# SVN Server occupying a lot of space

Tags: svn

I have created an SVN server long time back. I have been storing some binary files (doc files) along with codes. After every edit size increases cuz SVN saves a new copy of binary file. Now the svn is occupying alot of space.

Q1. I want to delete all previous revision of the binary files, keeping previous revisions of my codes intact, how do I do that?

Q2. Also is there any setting in SVN where I can customize it? Like "for specific folder dont store more than 10 revisions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. You're going to have to dump the repository and filter it. Have a look for "svnadmin dump filter".

(have a look here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter)

Q2. No, not as far as I know. However you could periodically run a script using the dump filter to delete previous revisions.

Generally if the binaries can be built from the source code in subversion you don't 'need' to store the binaries (however sometimes it can be useful!).

Comment: I am using SVN to store all documents (doc files). So that any document edited by any person in team will be available to all of the member in the team. I know svn is not the best approach for this, but I think it is (to track who edited what) untill I run out of space.

Comment: That makes sense. Especially with the Doc diff ability of TortoiseSVN. Perhaps the best solution is just to buy a new HDD? :)

Comment: hey ! whats this "Doc diff ability" of TortoiseSVN?